# Text Referencing a column in related function DAX

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I was wondering why doing the following doesn't work in DAX (it would be much neater than a nested IF), or even if there is a way to get it to work.

```
=RELATED("MVD["&[scenario_id]&"]")
```

Description of the data: 2 tables, the table that related is pulling the column reference based on a value filled in the other row. 
Running the above formula gives you the following error: Function RELATED expects a fully qualified column reference as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work.

As noted by the error, `RELATED()` requires a `column reference` as its argument. What you're passing to the function is a `string` e.g. `"MVD[1]"`, but still not a column reference, `MVD[1]`.

So I'm afraid `IF()/SWITCH()` is already the best you can do.